# To be or not to be - read out

Tags: tenses

I'm not a native speaker in english and writing a short piece about scientific detectors. Every time, an image is taken, there is the process of getting the signal from the device, referred to as "readout".

My question is, which is better:

"Every time the detector is read out..." vs. "Every time the detector is being read out..." or is it better to refer to the term readout directly as in "Every time a detector readout is done..."?

Comment: The first sounds most natural to me.

Comment: You can also just say "Every time the detector is read". We don't usually use "out" as part of the verb, it's only used when we turn it into a noun.